# android c++ undefined reference to eglGetCurrentContext

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

i am trying to get the current OpenGL context on android in c++.

but i get a compile time error, how can i get the current context?

the error:

```
undefined reference to eglGetCurrentContext()
```

the code:

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

void foo()
{
    EGLContext ctx = eglGetCurrentContext();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing libEGL from your make file library list.

Assuming you are using CMake files, you need something like this in your make file:

```
# Include libraries needed
target_link_libraries(
            GLESv2
            EGL)
```

Note `GLESv2` not needed for this error, but given you include the GLES2 header, it's likely you'll need the GLESv2 library at some point ...